# Linked lists with structures

Tags: c

I am trying to implement an array of linked lists. Now the linked lists contains a struct not a single data. I am not sure how to proceed with this. When I do the following I get a lot of errors.

How should I go about this ?
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(){

    int i,j;

    typedef struct{
        int a;
        int b;
    }Integers;

    typedef struct{
        Integers Int;
        struct Node *next;
    }Node;

    Node  *curr,*head,*nullhead;
    curr=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)*100);
    //head=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)*100);


    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        head[i]= NULL;
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            curr[i].Int.a=j;
            curr[i].Int.a=j;
            curr[i].next=head[i];
            head[i]=curr[i];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "I get a lot of errors" What are the errors?

Comment: why are you doing head[i] when it hasn't been assigned or allocated?

Comment: Btw: do not use `void main()`. Use `int main(void) { /*...*/ return 0; }` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*...*/ return 0; }` instead.

Comment: It has been assigned. head[i]=NULL. but It is of type NODE and not a simple pointer. So I do not how to go about. I was using array of structures before but wanted to know whether it could be done with linked lists. Essentialy I need a single row or a single column of linked lists where each Node consists of a struct integer

Comment: If you want an array of pointers each of which points to the start of a list, you need `Node **head` so that `head[i]` is a `Node *`.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. The problem is with this lines  curr[i].next=head[i]. Is this line correct

Comment: And in any event, before you can perform `head[i] = NULL`, you must assign a valid value to `head` itself.  I think this is what @pzaenger was getting at.

Comment: http://ideone.com/OTh0R5 also your typedef of `Node` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys I will work on it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
  int data;
  struct _node *next;
} Node;

Node *addfrontnode(Node **head,int data){
  Node *curr;

  curr = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  curr->data = data;
  curr->next = *head;
  return curr;
}

int main(void) {
  int i, j;

  Node **head, *curr;
  head = (Node **)malloc(sizeof(Node *));

  for(j=1; j<=10; j++)
  {
    head[j] = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    for(i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
      curr = addfrontnode(&head[j],i);
      head[j] = curr;
    }
  }

  i = 10;

  while(head[i]) {
    printf("%d\n",head[i]->data);
    head[i] = head[i]->next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to ask if this logic is good !. As I asked before I am trying to create an array of linked lists. The above code accomplishes this. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2):

There are a lots of problems in your code.

**1. `main()` prototype**

the prototype of the function `main` is well defined in the standard and should be either `int main(void) { }` or `int main(int argc, char **arg) { }`

**2. declare your structures in a header file**

Some people may argue but, it's better to declare your structure in a header file. This way you can include this header file whenever you need to use your structures and `typedef`. Ok, it's just about clean and reusable code...

Also, keep in mind the naming convention in snake case. Hence, you should use lower case name for your struct.

**3. algorithm logic**

I bet you would like to create an array of linked list. The logic you have is kinda wrong. It just doesn't make any sense.

You try to access to `head` elements, but you never allocated them. Moreover, you should allocate an array which holds **pointers** not structures. So, for your array, you should have `node** array = malloc(sizeof(node*) * size_of_array)`. This way, in every element, you will store the head of every linked list you created.

The way you allocate your structure isn't very nice neither reusable. You should have a function, which allocate a new element, bind it to the list and return a new element.

You should always check system call return values.

---

**SOLUTION**

*Note: I changed the structures names. Be careful.*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct point_s
{
    int x;
    int y;
} point;

typedef struct node_s
{
    point coord;
    struct node_s* next;
} node;

node* add_front_node(node** head)
{
    node* new_elem;

    new_elem = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_elem != NULL)
    {
        new_elem->next = *head;
        *head = new_elem;
    }
    return new_elem;
}

node* create_list_of(size_t size)
{
    node* list = NULL;

    /* create the list */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /* add a node to the list */
        node* new_node = add_front_node(&list);
        if (new_node == NULL)
            return NULL;
        /* set content with random value */
        new_node->coord.x = i;
    }
    return list;
}

void print_array_linked_list(node** array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("array element :%d\n", i);
        node* head = array[i];
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\n", head->coord.x);
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /*
    * Create array of linked list
    * Note the `node**`, it's an array which hold pointers
    * on node structure which represent the beginning of
    * your linked list! Not directly node structure !
    */
    node** array = malloc(sizeof(node*) * 10);
    if (array == NULL)
        return -1;

    /* Fill the array */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        array[i] = create_list_of(10);
    }

    print_array_linked_list(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what  I had in mind but can list be an array, such that list[j] represents a linked list. For example I want to have an outer loop , before i=0:9 say j=1:100 and create list[j].

Comment: So you want to create an array where each element holds a linked list. Let's say an array of 10 linked lists. I will update the solution.

Comment: Yes !. Thanks a lot !

Comment: If it fits your need, don't forget to validate the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This was exactly I had in mind. It was very helpful. I haven't modified it for my needs yet since I am trying to wrap my head around linked lists. Thank you once again.